# /etc/X11/Xsession & LightDM

Tags: xorg, 14.10, lightdm, display-manager, lxsession

I'm running Lubuntu 14.10. It seems that LighDM invokes `/etc/X11/Xsession` only if directed to so by the user. In fact there is no shadow of it in `lightdm-session` wrapper.

- `startx` command line (wrapper around xinit for reasonable defaults) uses `~/.xinitrc` if exists, otherwise uses `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.
- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` sources `/etc/X11/Xsession`, that redirects output to `.xsession-errors`.
- `/etc/X11/Xsession` sources `~/.xsessionrc` if exists, then executes `~/.xsession` if executable, sources if not.

What happens when using lightdm? If it doesn't source `/etc/X11/Xsession`, how could it possibly redirect errors to error-file `~/.xsession-errors` (I couldn't find any informations on other scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`)?

The man page for Xsession documents `~/.xsessionrc` and `~/.xsession`. It says that `~/.xsessionrc` is only for setting variables and the `~/.xsession` is for executing commands, but `~/.xsession` gets sourced only if I create a custom `*.desktop` file in `/usr/share/xsessions/` for it. Should I create a custom `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` file (like `40x11-common_xsessionrc` works for `~/.xsessionrc`), or just use `~/.xsessionrc` to add any scripts?

Also, I'd like to know how x-window-manager and x-session-manager work through alternatives. I noticed that they seem to work if no `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession` exist, and apparently they work only when running startx.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: By the way I'd have another question. Ubuntu's man suggests creating a custom *.desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions with line Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession in order to set custom settings in ~/.xsession. That means, running another wrapper after /usr/sbin/lightdm-session, which in this case would be /etc/X11/Xsession; that will result in everything under /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ being applied twice. So wouldn't it be better to create a script in /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ to source ~/.xsession? Any help appreciated.

Comment: In order to use ~/.xsession through /usr/sbin/lightdm-session, it was useful to me creating a new script in /etc/X11/Xsession.d which  I named 45x11-common_xsession. Since variables are all well defined into the wrapper, I just added the following lines:  if [ -r "$USERXSESSION" ]; then
  . "$USERXSESSION"
fi                                                            This way the wrapper will source ~/.xsession file too, after having sourced ~/.xsessionrc. Hope this might be useful.

Comment: If you can answer part of your question, pleas just create an answer yourself, that's perfectly normal. The comments are only temporary ang can get lost.

Answer (score 1):

This bug

> [Bug #1001035 “lightdm uses a hardcoded path to .xsession-errors,...” : Bugs : lightdm package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1001035)

states that **LightDM** has the path for `$HOME/.xsession-errors` hard-coded in its source. And that *really* should be configurable.

Sadly, “modern” display managers seem to often not care about `/etc/X11` much anymore, and re-invent the wheel… badly.
Probably because it is rather hard to find out why things are the way they are. (I tried. I still don’t know why there are so many files/scripts and what all their purposes are.)

E.g. SDDM doesn’t use `.xsession-errors` at all, and logs to some other strange location, if at all.

---

### Addendum

**The second question** should really be separate.
Due to me still not knowing all about it, I can’t help with that.
But I think I can say that you probably shouldn’t create another custom session file.
Maybe the LightDM documentation helps you there…

**About the third question:** The man page for `xinit` and its associated man pages (from the same software package) explain this. There’s a list of alternatives, some in `$HOME`, some in `/etc`, some even in `/usr/share/…` sub-directories. But I think if there is none, some default is assumed too.
Sorry, this should probably be separate too. I only post what I do know.